# Hibernate sometimes works and sometimes doesn't

Tags: lvm, luks, hibernate, libreboot

My system is set up for hibernation and everything works mostly fine.
However sometimes the system won't hibernate. When I issue the hibernate command it disconnects WiFi but doesn't go to sleep. A few seconds later it reconnects WiFi. This is all I could observe. It doesn't matter wether I close the laptop lid or if I issue the `sudo systemctl hibernate` command.

**How can I troubleshoot and finally remove the problem?**

Here's my system Info:

- Librebooted X440p with fully encrypted lvm.
- Hibernating to swapfile:
- mkinitcpio: `HOOKS=(base udev autodetect modconf kms keyboard keymap consolefont block encrypt lvm2 filesystems resume fsck)`

If you need any further info, just ask along.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
I managed to get into the situation where the machine won't hibernate.
This is the output of swapon:

```
❯ swapon
NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/swapfile file  16G 256K   -2
```

Comment: 1. ensure you have enough swap, 2. if you have updated the system without a reboot, then hibernation may fail as some libs etc may have been deleted and will not survive when powered back up, therefor the system will stop it happening - at least from my experience.

Comment: Since I use a swapfile on my root partition (which has plenty of space) the swap size shouldn't be a problem. I can pay attention to the second suggestion, however in my experience it takes 2-3 recoveries from disk before hibernation won't happen anymore. How can I "ask the system" why it won't hibernate?

Comment: Hi It's still me but I clumsily deleted my former profile.

This is what I have found out in the mean time:

If hibernation works or not is not dependent on the number of restarts but rather on the amount of open Applications and even mor so on the number of "heavy" tabs in Firefox (Microsoft Teams, Google apps etc.)

However I do have twice the amount of RAM as my swapfile size. Why does that not suffice to hibernate?

Thanks